# Possessivform in "Philippinens Präsident braucht eine psychiatrische Untersuchung"

Tags: possessive

Ist der Titel des folgenden FAZ.net-Artikels korrektes Deutsch?

[Philippinens Präsident braucht eine psychiatrische Untersuchung](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/phillippinen-praesident-duterte-braucht-einen-psychiater-15485617.html)

Wenn nein, haben "die Philippinen" eine Possessivform wie "Deutschland" eine solche mit "Deutschlands" hat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mich dünkt dies falsch. Die Bezeichnung «die Philippinen» zeichnet sich durch zweierlei aus:

1. Sie steht im Plural.
2. Sie wird (wohl in Folge von 1) immer mit Artikel verwendet.

Damit gleicht die Bezeichnung derjenigen von anderen Inselgruppen, etwa «die Nikobaren» oder «die Andamanen» usw. usw. Dies ist auch sinnvoll, denn die Philippinen bestehen ja, obwohl sie ein Staat sind, durchaus aus einer Inselgruppe.

Nun könnte man wohl aus der Bezeichnung «die Philippinen» einen Genitiv bilden und ihn voranstellen, so ähnlich wie bei *Deutschlands Präsident:*

- Der Philippinen Präsident braucht eine psychiatrische Untersuchung.

Dies ist allerdings extrem altertümlich. Besser wären also eine Nachstellung:

- Der Präsident der Philippinen braucht eine psychiatrische Untersuchung.

Oder gleich in echtem Zeitungsstil – hier völlig angemessen und meiner Meinung nach am elegantesten:

- Philippinischer Präsident braucht psychiatrische Untersuchung

Comment: Dein letztes Beispiel vermisst die (natürlich angenommene, deswegen macht's hier nix) Aussage, dass es nur einen philippinischen Präsidenten gibt, die in den anderen Beispielen duch den bestimmten Artikel gegeben ist. Ansonsten kann ich nur beipflichten.